# How to append a thymeleaf variable in an <img > tag that has a src?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Cant seem to find the correct syntax for this?

```html
<img id='barcode' src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data="'+ ${var.membervar} + "'+&amp;size=100x100" alt="" title="HELLO" width="50" height="50" />
```

Comment: You have used `${`. Did you also mean to use a template literal? (Using back-ticks `\``)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Are you looking for JavaScript syntax?

Comment: I have a thymeleaf variable that I need to be appended right after where it says "data="

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should let Thymeleaf know you want to parse the `src` attribute by using `th:src`. Something like this would work ...

```
<img id='barcode' th:src="'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data='+ ${var.membervar} + '&amp;size=100x100'" alt="" title="HELLO" width="50" height="50" />
```

But for the fully qualified URLs you should be using [Thymeleaf Link Urls](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) where proper encoding will be applied for all your query parameters. For example ...

```
<img id='barcode' th:src="@{https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/(data=${var.membervar},size='100x100')}" alt="" title="HELLO" width="50" height="50" />
```